# Follow user walking using react-native-maps and expo-location

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I'm currently developing an university project in React Native (android app).
My goal in this component is to render a map where you can see your location, and it follows you as you walk.

**Problem 1**: there's a MapView props named followsUserLocation, but it only works on Apple devices. How can I do it on an android phone?

**Problem 2**: I'm saving the location on a state in order to reuse it everywhere else, but the Location object is empty on first render (or takes a second or two to get the location info from the emulator). Whenever I use the state where I saved that info I get an error since I have this delay.

Here's my location useEffect:

```
export default function App() {
      
      const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState({})
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
       
      const mapRef = React.createRef();
      React.useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          setIsLoading(true);
          let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== "granted") {
            console.log("Permission to access location was denied");
            return;
          }
    
          let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeInterval: 1,
          });
          //console.log(location);
          //console.log(location.coords.latitude);
          
          
            setUserLocation(location)
            setIsLoading(false);
          
          
        })();
      }, []);
```

I'm new in React Native, thank you for you patience! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on `followsUserLocation` it's iOS-specific and not offers more flexibility.

Ideally, a Custom Location maker is required which indicates the current user's location as she moves.

The expo-location package provides `Location.watchPositionAsync(options, callback)` method which continuously dispatches new user location information when she moves.

With this new information, you can update the location marker in realtime.